# SSL Certificate Failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip

Running Spyder under the Anaconda package 3.8 with python 3.6. Ever since April I have been receiving an error trying to install packages using pip with the error:

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scrapy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443)`

Does anyone have any way I can rectify this issue. This doesn't happen at my home PC. Thanks

Comment: *"This doesn't happen at my home PC."* - which I assume means that it happens on the work PC only. In this case there is probably some corporate firewall doing SSL interception. Check with your network administrators on how to proceed.

Comment: Should I ask them to open the website domain only? Thanks

Comment: Tell them your problem. Ask them if the make an exception or if you should configure your system with the proxyCA certificate provided by them or if your access is forbidden by policy anyway.

Comment: In diagnosis. Would my browser also not be able to hit the pip website? Because I can access the pip website itself from chrome

Comment: It might be that either your browser is configured to use a proxy which does no SSL interception or more likely that the proxy CA is centrally installed in the usual certificate stores on all machines in the company. But Python does not use the usual certificate store. Likely this is a duplicate to [pip install fails with “connection error: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: I had the org add the pypi.org to the list of SSL but that didnt work. I also see that my file doesnt have an .ini file thoughts? %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini